# Getting 404 when attempting to publish new package to NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I just created a [new package](https://github.com/supericium/pli).

I'm now trying to publish it to NPM for the first time like this:

```
    ole@MKI:~/Sandbox/pli$ npm publish  --access public
    npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 404
    npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-93-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/home/ole/.nvm/versions/v6.4.0/bin/node" "/home/ole/.nvm/versions/v6.4.0/bin/npm" "publish" "--access" "public"
    npm ERR! node v6.4.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
    npm ERR! code E404

    npm ERR! 404 Not found : @supericium/pli
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404  '@supericium/pli' is not in the npm registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/Sandbox/pli/npm-debug.log
```

I tried updating both NodeJS and NPM to make sure that I have the latest version, which are:

```
ole@MKI:~/Sandbox/pli$ node --version
v6.4.0
ole@MKI:~/Sandbox/pli$ npm --version
3.10.3
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense. Can't create a package because it doesn't exist. None of these answers solve the problem.

Comment: @Distortum Try running `publish` in verbose mode - in a very frustrating way, in normal mode many issues end up as 404 while the real reason may be 403 because of a variety of issues. Usually running the verbose mode makes the issue apparent.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You need to have registered "supericium" (`npm adduser`) as a username at the registry and be logged in (`npm login`) to publish under that scope.

- https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages
- https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages

Answer (score 68):

It's solved by `npm login` in my case, the error message is misleading

Comment: It works... but when I published my package to **npm** their website stopped to work and shows me `error loading page` :)))

Comment: Sidenote: The problem isn't the client but that the npm registry sends 404. I've been told that when you e.g. use verdaccio as a proxy, it sends 401 if the login info is incorrect. Which makes the client show the expected "you need to log in" message.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to use a new token instead of `npm login` - just make sure you remove `./.npmrc` too because the token there overrides the one you set in the `NPM_TOKEN` environment variable.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589655/package-is-not-publishing-to-npm-not-in-the-npm-registry#answer-70416103

Comment: You can check access with a command such as `npm access grant read-write <org>:developers <package>` as it gives you a proper error message!

Answer (score 24):

Came across this same error, and my issue was that the package was somehow set to "Read" access only. So I have to go to the NPM and update the package to "Read/Write" access:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: Spent so much time trying to fix it before I found this. Thanks ;)

Comment: NPM error messages are still confusing... Thanks for the hint, it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 13):

Nothing worked for me, except logging in again:

```
npm login
```

Hope this helps me or someone else in the future!

Answer (score 9):

You could also get this error when you change your password to NPM but you do not logout/login via your CLI. Using `npm logout` and then `npm login` worked for me.

Comment: Ugh... This was it for me.  There is nothing telling you you're not logged in.

Answer (score 6):

in my case I had to verify the email address. even when `npm whoami` was telling me I was logged in fine.

Comment: How did you verify the email address? By executing `npm config ls` or something different?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I got this message because the token that I was using had been revoked. I fixed it by:

1. Generating a new access token in my npm account.
2. Modifying the line: `export NPM_TOKEN="<token>"` in my .zshrc (or .bashrc) file
3. Entering `source ~/.zshrc` in the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

This error appeared for me in two cases:

1. When I wasn't logged in. You can check whether you are logged in or not by `npm whoami`, then if not logged in `npm login`.
2. When I didn't have right to publish to the repository. In this case make sure you are added to the organization which owns the repo.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was missing the `repository` field in the `package.json` of my new package that I was trying to publish.

```
"repository": "git://github.com/your-org/your-repo-name.git"
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository

Answer (score 4):

I just logged in to npm by using `npm adduser` command and it worked fine.

Comment: Whoa! This was the answer for me. Despite being authenticated via command line I had to re-add my user and retry the publish. Really bad CLI experience on that one.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i noticed that my **npm account username** in npm website is different than my **npm normal user name**. When i try to publish in console by login with normal username gave me this error.

> publish Failed PUT 404 npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 User not found

But after login to console with account name it has published successfully

Answer (score 1):

Once you successfully publish the package you may experience when you try to `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @xxx/yyy@latest
```

or something similar, regardless if you `npm publish` was successful. In this case make sure your `{main: 'file.js'}` in packages.json is there.

Ideally, you can call it `index.js` if you wish to leech directly from the package so you don't get things like `import * from '@xxx/yyy/file'`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I believe I enabled 2FA on `npmjs.com` so the publish token used in CD didn't work (should have thrown 401, but got 404).

Generating a new `automation` token on `npmjs.com` and updating the secret on my CD (GitHub actions) solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It took me way too long to figure out that the scope needs to match my npm username and not my GitHub account name.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but I successfully resolved it by uninstalling the LTS version, then installing Current version along with yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my two cents to the possible solutions

I was getting this error in a CI workflow, so no interactive login or things related.
Existing packages were working correctly, but adding a new one wasn't, I was getting a 404. I realized that it should be something related to the new package itself, not the CI environment, and it was.

The new package was missing two fields on its `package.json`, the `repository` and `publishConfig` fields.

Adding these two fields, it worked correctly (note that `repository` field is used in its expanded form, with the `directory` property)

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "ssh://git@github.com/__user__/__repo-name__.git",
  "directory": "packages/__new-package-name__"
},
"publishConfig": {
  "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was completely different.

I had to replace:

```
npm publish FOLDERNAME
```

with simply:

```
cd FOLDERNAME && npm publish
```

In my case I also had to manually specify the path of `.npmrc` using the `--userconfig` parameter:

```
cd myapp && npm publish -ddd --userconfig ../.npmrc
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix seemed to be making a new "team" in the organisation and assigning myself and my package to this.

My guess is that my NPM organisation requires users to have 2FA on and two users assigned to the 'developers' group didn't have this on.

Answer (score 0):

publish to npm.pkg.github.com, this error stems from incorrect 'name' in package.json.
name should be aligned to github scope.
so : @

then you can go ahead and publish.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the NPM token was pasted twice.

So check your token. This error may be related to incorrect token or missing permissions for that token.

The error message and HTTP Status are misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that my package name was scoped i.e. it had a `supericium`, for exmaple: @supericium/package-name (or @pryansh/react-audio-gear).

But the catch here is, that you can use a `supericium` to prefix your package-name only if you have an organization's account on npmjs.com and as I didn't had it so a workaround was to remove `supericium`.

```
// BEFORE
{
  "name": "@pryansh/react-audio-gear",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
// AFTER 
{
  "name": "react-audio-gear",
  "version": "1.0.0",
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case i accidentally typed `https://registry.npmjs.org` instead of `https://registry.npmjs.com` (.org vs .com)

Comment: The default in the docs lists `.org` as the correct URL - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#registry

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I had a typo when passing the otp param:

```
// Wrong:
npm publish --access public --opt 123456

// Correct:
npm publish --access public --otp 123456
```