# npm publish is returning 404

Tags: npm, npm-publish

i am trying to push a module to npm to but on running `npm publish` it is returning the follwoing error, i tried every example and solution that was suggested but not able to solve this.

I have tried --> [Getting 404 when attempting to publish new package to NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115101/getting-404-when-attempting-to-publish-new-package-to-npm) too but no solution. I have already shipped a couple of modules to npm but never faced this issue.

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 404
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 User not found : <package-name>
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '<package-name>' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by updating my `npm` version to version `5.6.0`.