# Package is not publishing to npm (not in the npm registry)

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I would like to publish my git repository to npm so I can use it in other projects. But when I run the `npm publish` command I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/vue-toggle-component
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'vue-toggle-component@0.1.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\niels\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-29T10_47_26_952Z-debug.log
```

When trying to bugfix, I have tried the `npm adduser` command and the `npm login` command to make sure I logged in. Both of these did not solve my problem since it looked like I was already logged in.

My `package.json`:

````
{
  "name": "vue-toggle-component",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
  "description": "## Project setup ``` yarn install ```",
  "main": "babel.config.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nehlis/vue-toggle-component.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Vue.js",
    "Toggle",
    "component",
    "Lightweight",
    "Checkbox"
  ],
  "author": "Niels Bosman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nehlis/vue-toggle-component/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nehlis/vue-toggle-component#readme"
}
````

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What command did you used exactly ? Was it `npm publish <folder>` ?

Comment: @Hollyol I just cd'd to the directory and ran `npm publish`. Nothing after that.

Comment: I share a [npm publish tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-publish-your-package-on-npm-7fc1f5aae600) and also, [a few answers from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115101/getting-404-when-attempting-to-publish-new-package-to-npm), but i can't help you further :/

Comment: I think in my case it's because I didn't have permission to publish a new package in the given `@namespace`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the `https://npm.pkg.github.com/` appearing in the error output, you are trying to publish to GitHub Packages and not the npm registry (which are still separate, although GitHub now owns npm). According to the [GitHub packages docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-a-package):

> GitHub Packages only supports scoped npm packages. Scoped packages have names with the format of @owner/name. Scoped packages always begin with an @ symbol. You may need to update the name in your package.json to use the scoped name. For example, "name": "@codertocat/hello-world-npm".

So you'll need to either change your configuration to point to the npm registry rather than the GitHub packages registry, or else change the `name` field in your `package.json` to be a scoped package name.

Comment: Thanks! I did that together with adding a .npmrc file containing `registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/@nehlis`

Answer (score 39):

Try `npm login`. In case of `npm publish`, sometimes misleading message is shown.

Comment: Even though this was not the accepted answer, this was the answer I needed. Don't forget to sign in via the CLI! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue the problem comes from the published package is not accessible so you will need to add `.npmrc` with your private repo to be like this

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/yourcompany
```

or

```
@yourcompany:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

Answer (score 5):

As another user mentioned you have to add yourself to the private registry of your company or organization. But if you don't have your .npmrc setup, this command will create the file automatically as well as update your registry:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.your-company-registry.npme.io/
```

However the most robust way is to simply do

```
npm login
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about authentication.

Seems like username/password auth is no more working with `npm publish`.

You need to generate Access Token
[image]

Then use it to publish

```
NPM_TOKEN=blahblahblahblaha npm publish
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and used almost all the valid solutions that I felt
If you published it on GitHub then this could be something that could help you.
like

- updating npm to the latest version
- setting registry using
  `npm config set registry https://registry.your-company-registry.npme.io/`
- resetting token

It still didn't work

If you have uppercase characters in your GitHub username, and if you are using the command provided by GitHub under the package section

Make sure to update your username when you run that command locally
By default, GitHub does not show uppercase characters in the command under the packages section.

So if your user name is `UserName123` and package name is `my-first-package`
the command that GitHub will show is

`npm install @username123/my-first-package@1.0.0`

see that the username is case-sensitive when you install a package
hence, update your command to

`npm install @Username123/my-first-package@1.0.0`

and hopefully it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

In the .npmrc file add the below code

```
always-auth = true
@your_company:registry=https://npm.artifactory.your_company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
registry=https://npm.artifactory.your_company.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
```

In GIT bash execute command

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

steps to publish correctly:

1.- set repository where you want to publish, you can change for you own registry server

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

2.- login (need previus register in npm or your custom registry)

```
npm login
```

3.- go your package and set your scope

```
cd /your/package/path
npm init --scope=@my-org
#or
npm init --scope=@my-username
```

4.- finally publish your package

```
npm publish --access public
```

ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, you can delete your `.npmrc` file and try publishing again `npm publish` (after logging in with `npm login`).

(The local .npmrc has precedence, which might override the publishing functionalities).

You can put it back when the publish is successful.